# Real time co-editing notebook plataforms

Tags: python, sql-server, cloud, real-time-updates

I work as a DS in a ver small company, so all of the DS team is very "young" in this field.

We are currently experiencies issues with cooperation, especific at the writing code moment.
We've tried with VScode live share which is a great extension but, due to our pc's limitations goes hard to work when we are working with big df.
I was looking over deepnote, which sounds really great, but is has no support with MSsql server.
so, any alternative? Also we're thinking in cloud migration, like azure or AWS, but I was unable to find a proper way to do it or if there we can work in real time co-editting

so, any help or advice?

Comment: It is *highly* unlikely you need multiple people to be accessing, editing, and seeing the changes of a single file or project in real time. What you want is Source Control; then you can each make your own changes, commit and merge them, as well as add other work flows like Pull Requests.

Comment: In  case, we are working in pairs, so we want,  like be writing in a jupyter notebook and discussing ideas trought call. 

I know that the git it's great but I'm think that wouldn't work for us by now, also we're not very familiar with git.